# Why is my Keras model only producing the same prediction?

Tags: python, keras

I'm having some trouble understanding why my Keras model has problems generating proper results (it now always returns `0`). I have been able to find some others with this problem ([ref 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=keras%20predict%20always%201&oq=keras%20always%20predicts%201), [ref 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=keras%20predict%20always%201&oq=keras%20always%20predicts%202)), but I haven't been able to understand the underlying cause.

Question: *Why is my model only giving one, constant prediction?*

#### Training Data Example

The last column is the prediction, 0 or 1.

```
32856500,1,1,200,6842314460,0
32800000,-1,0,0,0,0
32800000,-1,1,0,6845343222,0
32800000,-1,2,0,13692319489,0
32800000,-1,3,0,20539336035,0
32769900,-1,4,-30100,27389628085,0
32769900,-1,5,-30100,34239941481,0
32750000,-1,6,-50000,41091099905,0
32750000,-1,7,-50000,47945852379,1
```

#### Keras Code for Training

I'm using the `sigmoid` activation for the binary results. But I'm not sure if the issue lies here or in -for example- the `binary_crossentropy` or `SGD` optimizer.

```
def trainKerasModel(X, Y, path, dimensions):

    # Create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=dimensions, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(80, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(60, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(40, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Fit the model
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCHSIZE)

    # Evaluate
    scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
    Helpers().Log(model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100)

    # Save model
    with open(path+".json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model.to_json())

    # serialize weights to HDF5
    model.save_weights(path+".h5")

    Helpers().Log("Saved model to disk")

someFilePath = "file.csv"
dataset = numpy.loadtxt(someFilePath, delimiter=",")
dimensions = len(dataset[0]) - 1
trainKerasModel(dataset[:,0:dimensions], dataset[:,dimensions], someFilePath, dimensions)
```

#### Keras Code for Predictions

```
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model.load_weights(someWeightsFile)
Xnew = preprocess_input(numpy.array([[32856500,1,1,200,6842314460,0], [32800000,-1,3,0,20539336035,0], [32750000,-1,7,-50000,47945852379,1]]))
Ynew = model.predict_classes(Xnew)
print(Ynew)
```

Comment: Why are you using a network with only sigmoid activations? It is screaming of vanishing gradient problems.

Answer (score 0):

12 sigmoid fc layers will never learn anything. 
Read theory.
 maybe you sould try just 3 layers with tanh , and no af if tanh on input. -1 for false, 1 for true.
Also apply tanh to input datasincethey are not normalized. Also cross entropy has no sence if you have only one output.

plus extending 5 input to 120 features then 12 layers is horrible overfit. You should have here 3 layers like with ~20, 16,10 items, tanh, mse loss, ca 1e-3 1e-4 learning rate

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I’ll try. The reason I have 12 layers is because it gave the best results during training.

Comment: getting best results  is not that easy :D